# Find the derivative at the point $(1, \ln(\pi/4))$ of $x \arctan x = e^y$.

Tags: calculus

> Find the derivative at the point $(1, \ln(\pi/4)$ of $x \arctan x = e^y$.

So I think this may be an implicit differentiation problem.  I'm not exactly sure where to start.  I tried differentiating it with respect to $y$, but that won't work.
$\ln(x \arctan x) = y$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You need to differentiate with respect to $x$ because you are trying to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Yes, from $\ln(x \arctan x) = y$ you can use the chain rule a few times and get $\frac {dy}{dx}$  No implicit differentiation needed.

Comment: its asking me at the point (x,y) though instead of x.... do I just ignore that statement?

Comment: When we solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we will get both $x$ and $y$ in the derivative. Once we have $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we need to substitute $x=1$ and $y=\ln\frac{\pi}{4}$ to find the derivative at that point.Once we have $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we need to substitute $x=1$ and $y=\ln\frac{\pi}{4}$ to find the derivative at that point.

Comment: @orangespire Asking for the derivative "at the point $(x,y)$" is the same as asking for the derivative at $x$ in this case, since this is actually a function of $y$. It's possible (say, if the right hand side were $y^2$ instead of $e^y$) that there could be multiple points on the right-hand side for which $x=1$, in which case the $y$-value would have to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using implicit differentiation, a simpler approach is to take the natural log of both sides then differentiate.

$$x\cdot\arctan x=e^y \rightarrow \ln(x\cdot\arctan x) = y$$

Now just differentiate, using the chain and product rule

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{1}{x\cdot\arctan x} \cdot \left(\arctan x \space + \space \frac{x}{1 + x^2}\right) \\
\end{align}

Plugging in the point $\left(1, \ln (\pi/4)\right)$ yields the following

\begin{align}
f'(1) & =\frac{1}{1\cdot\arctan 1} \cdot \left(\arctan 1 \space + \space \frac{1}{1 + 1^2}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cdot \left( \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& = 1 + \frac{2}{\pi}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\frac{d}{dx}(\arctan x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\ln x=\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to find the derivative, which almost certainly refers to $\frac{dy}{dx}$. When we solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we will get both $x$ and $y$ in the derivative. Once we have $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we need to substitute $x=1$ and $y=\ln\frac{\pi}{4}$ to find the derivative at that point.

Now, here is our equation:
$$x\cdot\arctan x=e^y$$
Take the derivative of both sides:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x\cdot\arctan x)=\frac{d}{dx}(e^y)$$
Let's do the right side first since it's shorter. Here, we use chain rule. First, we take the derivative of $e^y$ with respect to $y$ to get $e^y$ and then we multiply by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, which is $\frac{dy}{dx}$. This gives us:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x\cdot\arctan x)=e^y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Now, on the left side, we use product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)\cdot\arctan x+\frac{d}{dx}(\arctan x)\cdot x=e^y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\arctan x+\frac{x}{x^2+1}=e^y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Now, we want to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, so we divide both sides by $e^y$ and switch the sides to get:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\arctan x+\frac{x}{x^2+1}}{e^y}$$

Finally, we need to find the derivative at $(1, \ln \frac\pi 4)$. This means $x=1$ and $y=\ln \frac\pi 4$, so:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\arctan 1+\frac{1}{1^2+1}}{e^{\ln \frac\pi 4}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac\pi 4+\frac 1 2}{\frac\pi 4}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Comment: I believe there's a typo when you evaluate the derivative (i.e. should be $e^{\ln \pi / 4}$ not $e^{\ln 4}$)

Comment: @ApprenticeOfMathematics Thanks for the catch!

Comment: No problem man! :)

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

As Noble Mushtak answered, the problem with $x \tan^{-1} (x) = e^y$ is quite simple. Let us make it more complex and consider $$x \tan^{-1} (x) = f(y)$$ where $f(y)$ is any function of $y$.

In this case, as you suspected, you would have needed the differentiation of the implicit function $$F=x \tan^{-1} (x) - f(y)=0$$ The partial derivatives being $$F'_x=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\tan ^{-1}(x)$$ $$F'_y=-f'(y)$$ using the implicit function theorem leads to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\tan ^{-1}(x)} {F'_y}$$